# Discharging a Li Polymer battery

Tags: batteries, lithium-polymer

I have a LiPoly battery (3.7V 650mAh, similar in size/shape to a standard AA) that was part of an e-cigarette assembly. While attempting to remove another part of the assembly, I accidentally separated the battery from the assembly.

The battery still has both leads attached and is fully charged. I would like to fully discharge this battery for safety reasons, and am not sure exactly how to do that. As the battery is still in good shape, I would optionally like to keep the battery for some other hobby use so destroying it is not ideal.

**What should I do to safely discharge this battery so I can store it without worry?**

Comment: If you want to keep it, discharge it with a resistor or electronic load until the open-circuit resting voltage is 3.8V or just a bit higher and store it. Make sure it cannot short in storage. If you want to get rid of it later, discharge it with a resistor all the way to zero volts, and then dispose of it per applicable law.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid destroying it, charge it up and then simply tape the leads.  60~70% full charge gives the longest shelf life. Deep discharge will destroy the battery fairly quick before you want to use it again. It should read 3.5 to 3.6V after  6 mos depending on quality of battery.

Comment: I believe storage temperature also affects self-discharge rate.